# Jquery Dynamic Button to call HTML Form Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following HTML code which allows me to remove a product when the button Remove is clicked.

```
<table class="cart-table">
    <tbody class="cart-body">
        <form method="POST" class='form-product-ajax' action='{% url "shopping-cart-remove" %}' data-endpoint='{% url "shopping-cart-remove" %}'>
            {% csrf_token %} {% for item in cart.items %}
            <tr class=cart-product>
                <td>{{ item.quantity}} x {{ item.product.name }} {{ item.subtotal }}
                    <input type="hidden" name='id' value='{{ item.product.id }}'>
                    <button class='remove-btn'>remove</button>
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
    <tr class="cart-total-sec">
        <td class="cart-price">{{ cart.total }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get this working using Jquery/Ajax and currently stuck on the following point. I can dynamically create a Remove button and I assign a class of 'remove-btn' to it but I still can't remove a product. How do I code the Jquery so that clicking on the dynamically generated button executes the action specified on the HTML form action?

```
                 $.each(data.products, function(index, value) {
                     console.log(value)
                     console.log(data.count)
                     var removeSpan = thisForm.find(".remove-btn")
                     cartBody.append("<tr><td>" + value.quantity + " x" + "</td><td>"+ value.name + "</td><td>" + "£" + value.price + "</td>" + "<td><button type='submit' class='remove-btn'>Remove</button></td></tr>")
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, I don't see how the other answer clarifies this use case

Comment: You are asking how to bind on "dynamically generated button".  The duplicate question linked to addresses this question specifically.

Comment: You want the form `form-product-ajax` to be submitted with ajax to be submitted when someone clicks `remove-btn` button?

Comment: Yes that’s right